# HTTP header User-Agent in iOS5

Tags: ios

Recently I am developing for an iOS application which consumes .net web services. In that for a post request to a web service method call, I accidently specified user agent in http header to be the one

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDS; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; BRI/2)

The web service call is done via simply NSURLConnection.
Also I am able to run that application on iOS device with a successful call
to that web service method. My question is that does iOS ignores any specified user-agent in HTTP Header? Why does the code works with such a non compatible user-agent [at least theoretically]?

Answer (score 0):

Servers use the User-Agent string in at least two ways:

1. **Collect statistics** about what web clients are being used to access the server. This can help the humans that run a web site do a better job.
2. **Provide a better user experience** by tailoring the output to the capabilities of the client. For example, many web sites will provide pages customized for small screens when they detect (via the User-Agent value) that the client is a phone or small tablet.

When you're making a call to a web service, though, you're usually expecting XML or JSON output that really doesn't need to be customized for a given browser because: a) the request probably isn't coming from a browser in the first place, and b) the content is unlikely to be rendered onto the display (at least not directly). So the User-Agent string may not make any difference in the way the server responds to your web service request. Or at any rate, providing a User-Agent string that says "MSIE" when you make a web service request from an iOS device may not make a difference in what you get back.

Now, that's not to say that the User-Agent string never makes a difference. I don't know if it's common practice or not, but it would make a lot of sense to have clients provide a sensible User-Agent in cases where you control both client and server. Having the client include its version would let a server provide different output depending on the client version, so you could make changes to the API without breaking existing clients.